# Caller property of JS for "foo = function()" style of coding

Tags: javascript, function, function-expression, javascript-function-declaration

I want to use the property of "caller" for a function which is defined [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/caller?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fcaller)

It works fine for this style of function declaration

```
    function g() {
      alert(g.caller.name) // f
}

   function f() {
      alert(f.caller.name) // undefined
      g()
}

f()
```

[JSfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/avyPc/)

But then my function declaration is something like

```
    g = function() {
      alert(g.caller.name) // expected f, getting undefined
    }


   f = function() {
     alert("calling f")
     alert(f.caller.name) // undefined
     g()
   }

 f()
```

and I am getting undefined (basically not getting anything)

[JSfiddle for this](http://jsfiddle.net/pFhX7/)

Is there any way that I can use the caller property without having to rewrite my code? Also, I hope I have not made any mistakes in usage and function declaration since I am quite new to using JS.

Comment: See [JavaScript: var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname) and the [Function `name` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name)

Answer (score 1):

This function...

```
f = function() {
    g();
};
```

... does not have a name. It's an anonymous function, assigned to a variable with the identifier `f`. It will work as is if you make that function a *named function expression*:

```
f = function f() {
    g();
};
```

Note that since that anonymous function is called from the global execution context, it's `caller` property is `null` (note that in JSFiddle, it won't be `null`, it will be whatever function JSFiddle calls to invoke your code).

You have demonstrated one of the differences between function *declarations* and function *expressions*. Your first example shows function declarations. They must have an identifier. Your second example uses function expressions. The identifier is optional, and is only in scope within the function itself.